# filter document via aspell

Tags: batch-jobs, dictionary, aspell

I need to get a clean txt document and my first approach is to use aspell. The issue is I need it on batch, no interactive mode. Every txt file is piped to aspell and must be returned a new document with the non-dictionnary words deleted.

I've found just the inverse behaviour: list the non-dictionary words using

```
cat $file | aspell list | sort -u -f
```

Is aspell the correct tool to achieve that cleaned document folder? What about automatic substitution of misspelled words? (using a predefined list file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -E -e "s/$(aspell list <file | sort -u | paste -s -d'|' |
               sed -e 's/^/\\b(/; s/$/)\\b/' )//g" \
    file > newfile
```

This uses [command substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution) `$(...)` to insert the output of `aspell list <$file` into a `sed` search and replace operation.

`aspell`'s output is also unique sorted and `paste` is used to join each line with `|`.  Finally it is piped through sed to add `\b` word-boundary anchors as well as open and close parentheses.  All of which constructs a valid extended regular expression like `\b(word1|word2|word3|...)\b` to use as the search regexp in the `sed` search and replace command.

You can test the result of the entire command with, e.g., `diff -u file newfile`

AFAIK, `aspell` doesn't have an auto-correct mode.  This is probably a Good Thing.

Comment: Hi cas, tested your code but the file comes out untouched

Comment: Try the updated version.  The first had two problems - 1. `aspell` reads from stdin, not a file 2. `grep -v` would never have done what you want, it would have removed the entire line on any match, not just the matching word.

Comment: Updated version just strips words but is ripping apart some words that are contained inside too: vg. citizenship would be converted to citizen if ship is not in dictionnary. That is too bad

Comment: ok, that just means the regexp needs to be further modified to have word boundary anchors....i really should have thought of that earlier.  i'll update my answer.